# How to Grab GL.currentContext from a Thread?

Tags: rust, pthreads, webgl, webassembly, emscripten

I'm currently trying to use GL.currentContext from my render thread (separate from the main thread).

When I grab GL.currentContext by hand in the Javascript console on the main thread, it'll give me `Object { handle: 2320952, attributes: {…}, version: 1, GLctx: WebGLRenderingContext, initExtensionsDone: true, maxVertexAttribs: 16, clientBuffers: (16) […], tempVertexBufferCounters1: (22) […], tempVertexBufferCounters2: (22) […], tempVertexBuffers1: (22) […], … }`.

When I grab GL.currentContext by hand in the Javascript console on the render thread (also via inline Javascript on the render thread), it'll give me an integer such as 2320920.

I create the WebGL context via:

```c
EMSCRIPTEN_RESULT create_webgl_context() {
    EmscriptenWebGLContextAttributes attr;
    // attr.explicitSwapControl = 0;
    // attr.renderViaOffscreenBackBuffer = 0;
    attr.proxyContextToMainThread = EMSCRIPTEN_WEBGL_CONTEXT_PROXY_FALLBACK;

    emscripten_webgl_init_context_attributes(&attr);
    EMSCRIPTEN_WEBGL_CONTEXT_HANDLE ctx = emscripten_webgl_create_context("#canvas", &attr);

    return emscripten_webgl_make_context_current(ctx);
}
```

The Firefox error message is `TypeError: GL.currentContext.tempVertexBufferCounters1 is undefined`. Chrome has a different message that points to the same error.

This error specifically occurs on:

```rust
#[cfg(all(target_family="wasm", target_os="emscripten"))]
unsafe {
    // This line of code causes the error
    emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(render_loop, Box::from(&mut loopstruct), 0, 1);
    }
```

When I modify the below loop to run instead of `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg`, it'll work, but it'll be so fast that I think it can cause epileptic seizures and it doesn't take user input.

```rust
#[cfg(not(all(target_family="wasm", target_os="emscripten")))]
loop {
    let exit_loop: bool = render_loop(Box::from(&mut loopstruct));
    if exit_loop {
        // Ending Loop
        break;
    }

    // Slow Down Rendering (60 FPS)
    thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 1_000_000_000u32 / 60));
}
```

How would I set the GL context so it's available from `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg` on the render loop?

Comment: In the event if it's a bug not on my end, I opened a bug report at https://github.com/Rust-SDL2/rust-sdl2/issues/1312